# Is there a way to see all public methods available in a solidity contract?

Tags: ethereum, solidity

If I only have the contract address of a deployed solidity contract, is there a way to get the available public methods for that contract?

Comment: You just type it into etherscan and look at it. Did you mean in javascript?

Comment: I mean how to know which public methods are available in the contract for a client app (can be javascript) to interact with the contract. Basically the ABI.

Comment: Yes you just type the address into etherscan, the abi and source code are there.

Answer (score 1):

If you do not have [the contract ABI files](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/234/what-is-an-abi-and-why-is-it-needed-to-interact-with-contracts) you cannot know its public methods easily. Unless you reverse engineer the smart contract bytecode, but this is advanced method and not available unless you are an expert.

Comment: Yeah I mean if the ABI is not available. Thanks for the answer.